# Nginx rewrite local file path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Is it possible to make this kind of url rewrite?

Request url:
https://image.domain.com/listing/1_10_iP2LROSEafC01584630756.jpg
Rewrite to:
https://image.domain.com/images/i/P/2/L/iP2LROSEafC01584630756.jpg

If /images/i/P/2/L/iP2LROSEafC01584630756.jpg exists in server, it's served, if not then query is redirected to php file /make_image.php

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Request url: https://image.domain.com/listing/1_10_iP2LROSEafC01584630756.jpg Rewrite to: https://image.domain.com/images/i/P/2/L/iP2LROSEafC01584630756.jpg

If you mean an external redirect, then this is achieved using the `rewrite` directive. Place the statement in the `server` block, or within a `location` block that handles these kinds of request (i.e. URIs beginning with `/listing/` and/or ending with `.jpg`).

Your question does not state what `1_10_` means, but let's assume that you want the two arbitrary numbers ignored.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/listing/\d+_\d+_(.)(.)(.)(.)(.*)$ /images/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

> If /images/i/P/2/L/iP2LROSEafC01584630756.jpg exists in server, it's served, if not then query is redirected to php file /make_image.php

This is achieved using a `try_files` statement within a `location` block that processes requests for URIs beginning with `/images/`.

For example:

```
location /images/ {
    try_files $uri /make_image.php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.